# Bootstrap TypeHead change the seperator character

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the  following  bootstrap type head character : http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/ in creating sentences, The plugin works fine but I would like to change the separator character which currently is a comma to another special character e.f ; or $ or # from , how can I achieve this ? 
Below is my code :

```
 var x = jQuery.noConflict();
    x(document).ready(function () {
        x(".inputs").tagsinput('items');

        x(".activities").tagsinput('items');
        x(".outputs").tagsinput('items');
        x(".shortterm").tagsinput('items');
        x(".intermediate").tagsinput('items');
        x(".longterm").tagsinput('items');

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/#options) of the plugin you are using, you can specify the `confirmKeys` option which:

> Array of keycodes which will add a tag when typing in the input. (default: [13, 188], which are ENTER and comma)

So if you wanted to add `;` for example, you would use the ASCII code 59:

```
$('input').tagsinput({
  confirmKeys: [13, 188, 59]
});
```

[Other codes are](http://www.asciitable.com/):

```
$ 36
# 35
```